# Is DocumentCSS interface from DOM Level 2 Style Specification implemented anywhere?

Tags: css, dom, specifications, w3c

CSS Cascade and Inheritance spec defines the so called ['Override origin'](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#origin) for style sheets that links to [DocumentCSS interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-DocumentCSS) (from the DOM Level 2 spec from the year 2000). This seems to be the only mention of this interface on the W3C site (except of short conversation in the www-dom mailing list from 2008). The DOM Level 2 spec has the following text about it:

> The expectation is that an instance of the `DocumentCSS` interface can be obtained by using binding-specific casting methods on an instance of the `Document` interface.

Is this mechanism implemented anywhere? Is it possible to play with these 'override styles' and to see the `DocumentCSS` interface in action?

Comment: Mozilla has [bug 45424](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45424) but since `getOverrideStyle` is not in CSSOM spec I don't think it will be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorta exists in WebKit (via KHTML) but not really, [because the implementation just returns null](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/d6450206514f78ce2e8b4153588bf6974af41975/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp#L4210).

And that just-return-null implementation ended up in Chrome too [but was subsequently removed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/s3ezjTuC8ig/_IBbI5svjDoJ).

Also, as a comment above notes, [a Firefox feature request has been open for it for 10+ years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45424).

As far as Edge, there’s no indication it’s been implemented there yet either.

So it seems the answer is, it’s never actually been supported anywhere. Maybe somewhere in the [CSS Houdini plans](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/05/houdini) there’s something that will provide the same functionality?

Comment: That first sentence gave me the biggest laugh in a while. Thanks. Typical WebKit/KHTML "I support it lol jk I don't" shtick.

Comment: It turned out that SMIL, per spec, [used the override level of the cascade for its animation results](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1385). Does anyone know how this was implemented in browsers that support SMIL?